# What is the text used for making a siyum on Zohar?

Tags: torah-study, siyum, zohar

I have heard plenty of times that there are public completions of the Zohar, but I haven't been able to find a source of a text which would be used for the siyum. Is it a hadran?

Comment: Do you know anyone or any organization that has organized or celebrated such an event?

Comment: I know this has been done plenty of times in Eretz Yisroel. As for specific group - not off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I was told it is the same way. From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ppm3Y9TD0Tc) it's apparent that it is this way as well.